# Just out of curiosity: Since when did answered questions come in the unanswered tab?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, unanswered-questions

[image]

Is this a bug? Or are my eyes fooling me?

P.S. For those who didn't notice, an answered question is in the unanswered tab.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Stack Exchange definition of "unanswered" is "has no answers with a score of 1 or more." 0-score answers or answers with a negative score do not count.